# Split an array into uneven chunks according to difference between values

Tags: python, arrays, split

I a set of x and y data showing a background curve and 6 peaks. I have created a function that removes the background data and creates a new array with only the x-values for the 6 peaks. I now want to conduct analysis on each individual peak, so want to split my array into 6 smaller arrays that contain the values for 1 peak each. The x values are not in evenly sized chunks, but the difference between the x-values within a peak is no larger than 0.3 and the difference between the finish of 1 peak and the beginning of the next is around 1. So I'm thinking I can split the array into smaller arrays, the difference between the ending of 1 array and the start of the next being a set value ie.1. Any help appreciated

(edit: I've now managed to do the above, but the function only gives me 5 peaks and misses the last, 6th peak):

```
#xnb is x data without any background, for example:

xnb=[1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,3.4,3.5,3.6,3.7,7.8,7.9,10.8,10.9,11.0,11.1] #4     peaks

def peakfinder(xnb):
    pn=[]
    peakarrays=[]
    prevpoint=xnb[0]
    for point in xnb:
        dif=point-prevpoint
        if dif<=0.3 and dif>=-0.3:
            pn.append(point)
        else:
            peakarrays.append(pn)
            pn=[]
        prevpoint=point
    return peakarrays
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add [mcve]. So, it becomes easy for us to help

Comment: Maybe add some code snippets and or graphs, it is a bit hard to visualize what is actually going on here.